# IOS Gmail App White Spacing Issue Above Image

Tags: html, css, ios, gmail, darkmode

There appears to be a white line above the image in Gmail app on IOS in dark mode.

I've tried many solutions regarding this but could not remove the white line/space.

```css
img[class="visual"] {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<tr>
  <td bgcolor="transparent" valign="middle">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="content" align="center" width="640">


      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="transparent" align="center" valign="top" style="width: 640px;">
          <a href="TBC" target="_blank" alias="Banner"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150.jpg" width="640" height="250" style="display: block; border: none; max-height: 250px;" border="0" alt="Banner" class="visual" /></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: note that for email-templates you need to use inline-style all the way. CSS and head-style has very limited support.